# HTML 5 video tracking

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I am using video tag (of HTML5) for displaying video on my website.

1. Is there any way to track whether people actually played the video
   or not?
2. Whether video finished or not?
3. How to get the number of times video watched?

Comment: Maybe [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Media_events) may help you.

Comment: if you have a look at the HTML part of this sample - https://gist.github.com/Offbeatmammal/3718414#file-html5videoevents-html - it shows how to hook to various events. You'd want to fire a tracking event on the play() and ended() events to track what you need